# How to stop/exit a sub-classed method execution from its super class method in java

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Given the below snippet:

Super Class implementation:

```
@Override
    public void onDone(String taskName, JSONObject receivedData, @Nullable HashMap<String, String> sentData) {
        //checks the status for all done process decides to call the presenter failed or success
        try {
            boolean success = receivedData.getString("status").equals("success");
            if(!success){
                this.presenter.error(receivedData.getString("reason"));
            }
        }catch (JSONException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            this.presenter.error("An error occurred");
        }
    }
```

Sub-Class Implementation::

```
@Override
    public void onDone(@NonNull String taskName, @NonNull JSONObject receivedData,
                       @Nullable HashMap<String, String> sentData) {
        super.onDone(taskName, receivedData, sentData);
        //the expected data has been received we should act upon it
        //this DAO should know all the type of taskName it can handle and if it finds any that doesn't
        //matches any of its command let it exit
        Log.e(TAG, "Response : "+receivedData);
        Toast.makeText(this.presenter.getContext(), "Done with task", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(sentData!=null){
            sentData.clear();
            sentData = null;
        }
    }
```

What i want is that as soon as the **super.onDone** method detects an error, the process should end there and shouldn't bother running the body of the sub class method, is that possible in JAVA?

Comment: Unrelated comment: Why even catch the `JSONException`, you could use `receivedData.has("status")` before you access it?

Comment: That is because my server will always include the "status" key, the status can either be  equals to success or failed.. so one way or the other i have to know if it is successful or it failed.

Comment: The exception that you are catching, though, will only be hit when there is no `status` key.

Comment: yeah!! what is your point exactly.. im not concerned if the status key exist or not... im more concerned about the value the status holds and my action is based on the value it holds which is either success or failed.

Comment: A base class *is* a superclass. Please fix your confused terminology. You can use 'base' and 'derived', or 'super' and 'sub', and preferably not a mixture, and certainly not 'super' and 'base' when referring to different classes in the hierarchy, or, for completeness, 'derived' and 'sub' either. At present your question is meaningless. You *appear* to be using 'base' to mean 'sub' or 'derived', but it's up to you to clarify this.

Comment: Done in one place out of at least three.

Comment: My point was that the catch is not needed since you always have the status key, that is all.

Comment: @cricket_007 getString method throws an exception that i have to definitely catch.

Comment: @EJP done... done.. my bad

Comment: Still at least one left. See your title.

Comment: @EJP arrrrggghhh... now this is so embarrassing... feels bad :( ... thanks so much for pointing it out..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could either

- have the method throw an Exception (probably requires bigger refactoring to then deal with the exception)
- have the method `return false` (change the return type from `void` to `boolean`) and check the status in your subclass before proceeding. You could also return a more detailed status code.
- have the superclass set its processing status to an instance variable (`this.wentWell = true`) that the subclass can then check. The downside of this is that it introduces mutable state and is not threadsafe.
- (this is getting increasingly bad design): Have the superclass update the `HashMap` it received with some extra information for the subclass to pick up (`sentData.put("wentWell", "true")`). This is similar to how, say, a servlet filter passes data along by setting "request attributes". Depends on that map being updatable (which not be the case), potentially opens remote exploits via data injection (you are putting internal processing logic flags into a data structure that may be coming directly from who knows where).

Comment: Hmmmm.... okay, needed be sure... i was hoping there was something other than this... but this is fine... actually thought of the last option also, but like you said it isn't threadsafe... Thanks a lot.. i think i will go with the 2nd option that sounds more reasonable to me.

Comment: To this extent the second option is still the best for me